# Qr code generates different links with 2 parameters (img != href)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, email, qr-code

I want to kill myself.
I don't understand why when I send an QR (which has 2 parameters) in an email, I have 2 different links generated :

**With `<a> </a>`:**

```
string body = "<b>QR code: </b><br/>" + "<a href=\"" + resetLink + "\">" + "Click here" + "</a>";
```

Generated: http:/site.com/Account/Validate/?param1=xxx%26param2=yyy

It's OK.

**And, with `<img />`:**

```
string body = "<b>QR code: </b><br/>" + "<img src='" + resetLink + "' />";
```

Generated: http://site.com/Account/Validate/?param1=xxx

Where is my second param?

**ResetLink:**

```
string resetLink = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&amp;chl=http://site.com/Account/Validate/?param1=" + model.UserName + "%26param2=" + model.Token;
```

I use ASP .NET Mvc4 / Razor.

Comment: Your resetLink doesn't even have a `param2` in its definition. Non of the links generated in your question can be generated by the resetLink string in the code above. Please pay more attention.

Comment: The second param is the token

%26param2=anexempleToken

Comment: Why are you URL encoding &amp; before chl= ?
Try:
... cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl= ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the mailbox skips the last parameter, it is sometimes hard to predict (gmail alters the HTML).

I think you should URL-encode the whole URL, because the character `?` might be the cause of the problem. 
This would be

```
string resetLink = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=
http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2FAccount%2FValidate%2F%3Fparam1%3D" + model.UserName + "%26param%3D" + model.Token
```

I also replaced the ampersand before chl you encoded by its real character.